# PHP code.Display the seasons (round 2)

Tags: php

I posted yesterday and there was to many errors in the code so I went and started again.The code is not displaying anything is there something im missing.Im new to this so trying to learn.When I load this to my local host all it returns is 'invalid season'

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

$season = array('winter','spring','summer','autumn');

function getWinterMonths(){
$WinterMonths = array(
1 => array('November'),
2 => array('December'),
3 => array('January')
);
return $WinterMonths;
}

function getSpringMonths(){
$SpringMonths = array(
1 => array('February'),
2 => array('March'),
3 => array('April')
);
return $SpringMonths;
}


function getSummerMonths(){
$SummerMonths = array(
1 => array('May'),
2 => array('June'),
3 => array('July')
);
return $SummerMonths;
}

function getAutumnMonths(){
$AutumnMonths = array(
1 => array('August'),
2 => array('September'),
3 => array('October')
);
return $AutumnMonths;
}   



if($season  == "winter")
echo $WinterMonths();

else if($season == "spring")
echo $SpringMonths();

else if($season == "summer")
echo $SummerMonths();

else if($season == "autumn")
echo $AutumnMonths();
else{
echo "Invalid season entred";
}
```

Comment: You do not call "getSeasonMonths" but you call the variable ($seasonMonths) which is declared into a function... scope problem, right? Btw, $season is an array, it cannot be == "summer" ! but $season[1] or [0] can...

Comment: Could you please say what you are trying to achive?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be invalid. For example, you are comparing an string with an array:

```
$season = array('winter','spring','summer','autumn');
/* more stuff */
else if($season == "summer")
```

While `$season` it's an array, this condition will be always `false`.  If you change the comparison like something like this it works:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

$arrSeason = array('winter','spring','summer','autumn');

function getWinterMonths(){
$WinterMonths = array(
1 => array('November'),
2 => array('December'),
3 => array('January')
);
return $WinterMonths;
}

function getSpringMonths(){
$SpringMonths = array(
1 => array('February'),
2 => array('March'),
3 => array('April')
);
return $SpringMonths;
}


function getSummerMonths(){
$SummerMonths = array(
1 => array('May'),
2 => array('June'),
3 => array('July')
);
return $SummerMonths;
}

function getAutumnMonths(){
$AutumnMonths = array(
1 => array('August'),
2 => array('September'),
3 => array('October')
);
return $AutumnMonths;
}   


$season = $_POST['season']; /* For example get from post */
if($season  == "winter")
   echo getWinterMonths();

else if($season == "spring")
   echo getSpringMonths();

else if($season == "summer")
   echo getSummerMonths();

else if($season == "autumn")
   echo getAutumnMonths();
else{
   echo "Invalid season entred";
}
```

Comment: im getting  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in C:\wamp\www\3\script.php on line 44

Comment: Sorry I write in javascript LOL. I edit without VAR, but you must not copy and paste, you need to understand the code

Comment: Why do you put arrseason,is that an error you done for javascript.Im trying to figure it out.I get that I wrong at the header.

Comment: This code will not run never. This is an example of your errors. You are compare an string with an array (always false). You are calling inexistent functions with variables (`echo $SummerMonths()`), and you are not request the season from nowhere (I put an example with `$_POST`)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
```

Just checks if you have POST method, it will not get the post variable, you'd need to use $_POST for that.

You are not passing anything to the functions, I assume you want to pass season via $_POST so you'll need something along the lines of:
`$_POST['season']`;

Hope that helps

Comment: I have an index page where you post the season and the season you enter displays the months in that season.Sorry about being so vague